# In Rappid framework. Link Element fails to point to the port when recreating with fromJSON method

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I am creating the elements in the stencil area based only using the following definition

```
joint.util.defaultsDeep({
        type: 'app.RectangularModel',
        attrs: {
            root: {
                magnet: false
            }
        },
        ports: {
            groups: {
                'in': {
                    markup: [{
                        tagName: 'path',
                        selector: 'portBody',
                        attributes: {
                            'd': 'M0 -10 L-5 -10 Q-10 0 -5 10 L 0 10 Z'
                        }
                    }],
                    attrs: {
                        portBody: {
                            magnet: true,
                            fill: '#61549c',
                            strokeWidth: 0
                        },
                        portLabel: {
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fill: '#61549c',
                            fontWeight: 800
                        }
                    },
                    position: {
                        name: 'left'
                    },
                    label: {
                        position: {
                            name: 'left',
                            args: {
                                y: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                'out': {
                    markup: [{
                        tagName: 'path',
                        selector: 'portBody',
                        attributes: {
                            'd': 'M0 -10 L5 -10 Q10 0 5 10 L 0 10 Z',
                            'fill': 'purple',
                            'stroke': 'purple'
                        }
                    }],
                    position: {
                        name: 'right'
                    },
                    attrs: {
                        portBody: {
                            magnet: true,
                            fill: '#61549c',
                            strokeWidth: 0
                        },
                        portLabel: {
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fill: '#61549c',
                            fontWeight: 800
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        position: {
                            name: 'right',
                            args: {
                                y: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.prototype.defaults);
```

And after finishing the drawing in the paper area as usual (everything works fine), I have a save button in the toolbar. The functionality of the button is to save the drawing data into the API server to load it later.

I am getting the graph data using the function graph.toJSON() method to save on the server.  But when I am trying to reproduce the same graph JSON data, using the function `graph.fromJSON` the links are not pointing correctly to the ports.

**This is the original image drawn**

[image: Image drawn initially before saving]

**This is the image reproduced using `graph.fromJSON` method**

[image: Image reproduced in the paper using <code>graph.fromJSON</code> method]

**Problem:**

As you can see in the image when the graph data is reproduced in the graph using the function `graph.fromJSON` function, the links are pointing to the 0,0 location if the element instead of the ports drawn in the element.

Comment: Hi can you share a JSFiddle exposing this problem? I've had the same problem (not with rapid but with jointjs) and it involved an unexpected jquery ui interaction in my case.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I got assistance from the Rappid Team. Fixed it. Actually I was adding the graph data before attaching paper into the DOM. Thank you

Comment: Hi Jin, thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. I was adding the graph data before attaching the paper into the DOM. The graph renders fine when I am using `graph.addCells` after creating the paper and attaching it to the DOM.